# Performance Tips: To update a single document in cosmos db what to use server side javascript or .net api?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have to update one of the property of document in cosmos db. And this is a frequent call and concurrent as well as per business logic. In order to have a better performance - should I use server side javascript to update the document which will also handle race condition or should I use .Net Cosmos Db API? Please suggest.

I also want to race condition handled in a better way as the same record can be updated from multiple services? Also what should I do if the race condition fails? Should I put retry mechanism or simply return the error to the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I use server side javascript to update the document which will
>   also handle race condition or should I use .Net Cosmos Db API?

I don't think it would matter as both of them will eventually call the REST API to replace the document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/replace-a-document).

> I also want to race condition handled in a better way as the same
>   record can be updated from multiple services?

Cosmos DB provides `etag` based optimistic concurrency handling. In your scenario, you will include `If-Match` request header with the document's `_etag` property value. If the value matches with the etag value of the document on the server, the update will succeeed otherwise it will fail.

> Also what should I do if the race condition fails? Should I put retry
>   mechanism or simply return the error to the caller?

I don't think retrying with same parameters would help if you're implementing optimistic concurrency. In case an update fails because of this, you should fetch the latest document from the server, update it and then try to save it.